# Missing number, treated as zero. \ldf@finish\CurrentOption file English.ldf

Tags: errors, babel, greek

i will need your precious help. I am doing my final report for my school and i am writing in LaTeX. I want to write it in greek and i am using babel package. But when i complile it, display the title above: "Missing number, treated as zero. \ldf@finish\CurrentOption". File English.ldf. What is this and how can i fix it? I am newbie, so try to explain it as simple as u can.
Thank you for your time.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[English, Greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}

\title{An'aptuxh \latintext site \greektext gia diktuak'h dimiourg'ia \LaTeX\ \latintext Document Classes - Manual}
\author{\latintext Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

        \section{Poioi e'imaste}
        \section{per'i \LaTeX}{
            \subsection{Poioi to 'idrusan}
            \subsection{Pws prof'eretai}}
        \section{Fti'axe to dik'o sou \LaTeX\ \latintext Document}{
            \subsection{Korm'oc \LaTeX\ \latintext Document Class}
            \subsection{Basik'es Entol'es}
            \subsection{'Orise tic dik'ec sou entol'es }}
        \section{P'wc na fti'axeic to dik'o sou \LaTeX\ \latintext Document Class}{
            \subsection{Poia h diafor'a metx'u }}
        \section{xaxaxscxscs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The options to babel should be lowercase: try `\usepackage{english,greek]{babel}`

Comment: Consider switching to UTF-8 as input encoding, rather than `iso-8859-7`.

Answer (score 2):

On my system I get different errors; the first one is

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `English'. Either you misspelled it
(babel)                or the language definition file English.ldf was not found.
```

You don't get this probably because you're on Windows, where the file system is case insensitive. If an option, say `foo`, to `babel` is not predefined, the package looks for a file `foo.ldf` in the TeX tree.

In your case, on Windows, `english.ldf` is found because of case insensitivity. However, you get the error, linked to `\CurrentOption`,

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
```

because TeX *is* case sensitive and `english.ldf` expects `english` as the current option.

### Solution

Use the official options:

```
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
```

All options to `babel` are lowercase.